# Confused about string terminator in Perl

Tags: perl, terminator

I read several postings here about getting the error message -

> can't find string terminator "" anywhere before EOF ...
>
> can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF ...

I don't think I really understand it, although the take-home message is not to use single quotes.
So okay, I will try NOT to use single quotes. But still, if possible, could someone help me understand the differences between the two scripts, in terms of how Perl sees them differently

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#backwhacking
print "c:\\WINNT\\Profiles\\\n";
print 'c:\WINNT\Profiles\ ', "\n";

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#backwhacking
print "c:\\WINNT\\Profiles\\\n";
print 'c:\WINNT\Profiles\', "\n";
```

The first script runs fine with the output

```
c:\WINNT\Profiles
c:\WINNT\Profiles
```

whereas the second script gave me the same error code about not able to find script terminator "'"

And is there any "reason" why Perl programming needs to distinguish between with or without a space with single quotes? Sorry, but it seems somewhat trivial to a non-computer science person.

Comment: You will be happier if you use slashes in paths.

Comment: @tchrist I bet that in 20 years, 95% of Windows developers still will not have noticed that one simply can use slashes.

Comment: I think that your output example is bad. When tested, both 1st and 2nd print did print also trailing backslash. That is output was "c:\WINNT\Profiles\" and not "c:\WINNT\Profiles"

Comment: @tchrist: Unfortunately forward slashes work only internally for perl running on Windows. If a Perl program has to interface with other software then backslashes are essential. (`File::Find` is particularly bad at using forward slashes regardless of platform.) The only alternatives are either to work with backslashes throughout, or push paths through `File::Spec->canonpath` before output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

' style quotes use backslash to escape ' character.

So: `print '\''`; will print ' character, and not \' string.

when you print 'whatever\ ' - it will print >whatever < - with space at the end. But if you do:

```
print 'whatever \'
```

this is not terminated string, because the backslash escapes '. So the following `, "\n";` are treated as part of '' string.

Comment: In 'c:\WINNT\Profiles\ ', "\n";

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: sorry, I thought I deleted that incomplete message (click enter by mistake). My follow-up question is in this script, 'c:\WINNT\Profiles\ ', "\n"; didn't Perl see single quote first and if so, shouldn't it choose to "ignore" altogether the backslash being the "escaper"? If Perl still sees backslash as the "escaper", shouldn't Perl escape "W" and "P" also and prints out something like c:INNTrofiles?

Comment: No. Because in '' strings, \ escapes only two possible characters: ' and \. so \\ is changed to \, and \' is changed to '. That's all.